# Como lograr girar así un texto y que quede alineado a los bordes HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Buen día estoy intentando construir algo como el texto que esta rotado en la esquina inferior izquierda (el del copyright), pero no logro hacerlo, el diseño lo hice yo pero no he podido dejarlo idéntico en HTML y CSS

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código que has intentado? De ese modo podremos ayudarte con tu problema en concreto. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de esta forma

```
p {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```